# Retrieve a fixed number of random records from a Postgres database table

Tags: postgresql, sample

I have a table with partitioning by day. This table stores data for one month and there are about 3 billion of them, but many partitions in the table are empty.

How can I optimally select exactly 5000 random records from the depth of the entire table?

I'm thinking about `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (0.1)` with limit, but if empty partitions are included in the sample, then there are fewer than 5000 records. The query  `select *, row_number() over (order by random())` takes a long time to execute and loads the cpu.

Comment: You can consider several strategies: 1) Use an improved TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM method within a loop to accumulate the desired number of records. 2) Sample a few rows from each non-empty partition and union the results, ensuring a more uniform distribution. 3) Employ a random offset method, selecting rows based on a list of unique random numbers, though this can be CPU-intensive. 4) Combine TABLESAMPLE with a random offset approach to first narrow down the dataset and then apply randomness, potentially offering a balance between efficiency and randomness.

Comment: Try other table sample methods.

Comment: It depends what exactly you call *random records*. There is an easy way to get exactly `N` random records **quickly**, so long as said records are stored consecutively in a table (rather, in segments of the table). Does it count as random to you. I am asking because the records will not **look** chosen randomly if e.g. records are inserted in your table with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or a `SERIAL` in one of the columns. If you want to get random records from random segments, I am afraid it will inherently be slow anyway from reading the whole table from the disk.